# Compare files and select bigger one

Tags: file-comparison

There are two directories with many files. Those files are always matching in names and not always matching in size. For example:

```
/dir1
|-file1 (1 MB)
|-file2 (2 MB)
|-file3 (3 MB)

/dir2
|-file1 (1 KB)
|-file2 (2 MB)
|-file3 (10 MB)
```

As you see, filenames are match but filesize matches only in file2. 
How can I compare files in those 2 directories and select files only which are bigger? Output in example case must be "/dir2/file3".

If there is a file in dir1 that is bigger than the file with the same name in dir2 = then do nothing. I am interested only about files in dir2 that are bigger than ones in dir1

I've wrote a script, but it works only if one bigger file in dir2 was found.

```
#!/bin/bash
diff -q $1 $2 | awk '{ print $2,$4 }' > tempfile.txt
A=`cat tempfile.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
B=`ls -s $A | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
C=`cat tempfile.txt | cut -d ' ' -f 2`
D=`ls -s $C | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
if [ "$D" -gt "$B" ]; then
 echo $C
fi
```

Comment: "...but filesize matches only in file2" I'm not sure I understand this. What do you want to do if there is a file in `dir1` that is bigger than the file with the same name in `dir2`?

Comment: Hello, Niko, thnx for reply. "if there is a file in dir1 that is bigger than the file with the same name in dir2" = then do nothing. I am interested only about files in dir2 that are bigger than ones in dir1

Comment: Are the files with the same size identical? If yes, you might be able to use `diff -q dir1/ dir2/`

Comment: Panki, yes, names are same. But diff -q shows "all different" files while I need to find "bigger different" (NOT different files which are smaler)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

zmodload -F zsh/stat b:zstat

for file2 in dir2/*(.); do
    file1="dir1/${file2##*/}"

    if [ -f "$file1" ] &&
       [ "$( zstat +size "$file2" )" -gt "$( zstat +size "$file1" )" ]
    then
        printf '%s is bigger than %s\n' "$file2" "$file1"
    fi
done
```

This is a `zsh` shell script that uses the built-in command `zstat` to portably get the file sizes.

The script will loop over all regular files with non-hidden names in the `dir2` directory.  For each file in `dir2` it will construct the corresponding pathname for a file in `dir1`.  If the file in `dir1` exists and is a regular file (or a symbolic link to a regular file), the size of the two files are compared.  If the file in `dir2` is strictly bigger, a short message is outputted.

The pattern `dir2/*(.)` will match only non-hidden names of regular files in the `dir2` directory.  The `(.)` is a `zsh`-specific modifier for `*` that makes it match only regular files.

The expression `"dir1/${file2##*/}"` will expand to a pathname starting with `dir1/` and then containing the value of `$file2` with everything before and including the last `/` removed.  This could be changed to `"dir1/$( basename "$file2" )"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

get_attr() {
    # pass '%f' to $2 to get file name(s) or '%s' to get file size(s)
    find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "$2\n"
}

while read -r file
do
    (( $(get_attr "dir2/$file" '%s') > $(get_attr "dir1/$file" '%s') )) \
        && realpath -e "dir2/$file"
done < <(get_attr dir2 '%f')
```

This assumes all files in `dir2` have the same names as files in `dir1`, as you describe above.

`realpath` prints the absolute path of the file.

This script also compares hidden files (files that begin with a `.`).